# JQuery UI - Append Draggable to Droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you append an item being dragged to a target element on drop, using jQueryUI's draggables/dropables?  It looks like the way jQuery UI works right now is it just moves the items around on the screen via absolute positioning.  Unfortunately, this functionality makes form submissions useless, as you cannot get the positions of the values on submission.

Thanks in advance for any items/pointers!

Comment: In my experience, it actually modifies the DOM to reflect the new positioning; I know because I update lists (via AJAX) with it and that involves scanning the new div order in the 'completed' callback. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It sounds like you might be looking for sortable instead of draggble: http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want the dragged element to be detached from it's current parent and be appended to the new one, right? You can use a helper to do the dragging (so the original element is not affected) and, upon drop, detach it and append it to the target (thanks @Oleg and @Brian for improving over my original answer).

```
$(myDraggable).draggable({
    helper:"clone",
    containment:"document"
});

$(myDroppable).droppable({
    drop:function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

​
Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/PtLLf/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help mgibsonbr!  I really appreciate the time and effort it took for you to write this!

Comment: You don't need to use any global variable for that - ui.helper is your draggable jq object. You can get rid of start/stop methods, and on drop it should be ui.helper.detach().appendTo($(this)).

Comment: @Oleg thanks for the tip, as I've said I was sure there were better ways... Do you want to post your solution as an answer (so me and others can upvote it) or may I update mine? Feel free to use my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/PtLLf/43/) if you want.

Comment: @mgibsonbr please update yours, because I was originally looking at your solution when I figured out it can be simplified :)

Comment: `ui.helper.detach().appendTo($(this))` doesn't work for me while `ui.draggable.detach().appendTo($(this))` does. According to the doc, I think using `ui.draggable` in this scenario is correct.

Comment: @Brian if you use `helper:"clone"` then yes, it doesn't work, since the helper is a different element. Otherwise, it should work fine, as [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/PtLLf/43/) shows. Nonetheless, you're right, using `ui.draggable` is better, thanks for the tip!